# Hibernate get value of column from other table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have one Entity called Trade which can be mapped to a Table containing the attributes. Also this Entity, has a field, which stores the value from another table. My Trade table contains the primary key for the second table. I know how to get the whole second table as entity in my Trade entity, but i only want that 1 column.

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "Trade table")
@SecondaryTables(value = {
    @SecondaryTable(name = "2nd table", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "2ndtableID"))),
    @SecondaryTable(name = "3rd table", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "3rdtableID"))) })
public class TradeSearchResult {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long primaryKey;
    @Column(name = "col2", table = "2nd table")
    private String valuefrom2ndtable;
    @Column(name = "col3", table = "3rd table")
    private String valuefrom3ndtable;
}
```

as you can see i tried with `@SecondaryTables`, but the join were executed on the primaryKey from Trade entity. How can I use annotations to select the foreign key from trade table, join it to 2nd/3rd table and directly get only the value from col2/col3? Any suggestion is appreciated

Table Trade:

```
ID    col1   fk1    fk2
------------------------
1     abc    12     43      
2     def    23     32
3     ghi    34     21
```

Table 2:

```
ID    col2
----------
12    a
23    b
34    c
```

Table 3:

```
ID    col3
-----------
43    d
32    e
21    f
```

now my Trade class should have the Attributes:

```
Long id;
String col1;
String col2;
String col3;
```

The hibernate query: `from Trade` should give me in this example 3 Trades with the attributes:

```
Trade1: 1, "abc","a","d"
Trade2: 2, "def","b","e"
Trade3: 3, "ghi","c","f"
```

and i don't want to create an entity only to reach to the attributes `col2` and `col3`

EDIT:

A select statement would look like this:

```
select trade.ID,TICKET,table2.col2,table3.col2 from trade join table 3 on table3.ID=trade.FKtable3 join table2 on table2.ID=trade.FKtable2
```

if i execute this statement in sql server, it would give me the result i want to have. i want to map my class, so that hibernate generates this statement.

Comment: I have similar situation. Have you finally find a way to join value from another table without declaring an entity which describes another table?

Comment: @Cryptor i used `Criteria` API and mapped it that way. `valuefrom2ndtable` is fetched via a join inside the query. note that my `TradeSearchResult` is not directly mapped to any table, but my `Trade` class still is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround to this problem was to not map the `TradeSearchResult` to any table and use `Criteria`/`CriteriaQuery` API to fetch the data I needed. My `Trade` class is perfectly mapped to the Trade-Table and holds references to the objects of the other tables. Now comes how the query is build:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = emf.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<TradeSearchResult> query = cb.createQuery(TradeSearchResult.class); //type is the entity you want to map to
Root<Trade> r = query.from(Trade.class); //root must be entity from which you can access all data

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>(); //new list of predicates

predicates.add(cb.like(r.join("2ndTableEntityName").<String>get("valuefrom2ndtable"),"value to search for")); 
//get the needed value from 2nd table and map it to the field

query.multiselect(r.get("2ndTableEntityName")).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
//create the query and execute it
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
List<TradeSearchResult> results = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
em.close();
return results; //return results
```

This code returns a list of `TradeSearchResult` entities with only the needed fields and not the whole objects from other classes

Answer (score 0):

Based on [javadoc example](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/SecondaryTable.html) you should use `pkJoinColumn`and `foreignKey` to define witch columns should be used to join your tables.

// edit:

After your edition I tried to make some magic:

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "\"Trade table\"")
@SecondaryTables(value = {
        @SecondaryTable(name = "2nd table", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "col2", referencedColumnName = "id")),
        @SecondaryTable(name = "3rd table", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "col3", referencedColumnName = "id"))
})
public class Trade {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long primaryKey;

    @Column(name = "col2")
    private String valuefrom2ndtable;

    @Column(name = "col3")
    private String valuefrom3ndtable;


}

@Entity
@Table(name = "\"2nd table\"")
public class Table2 {

    @Id
    private long id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "\"3rd table\"")
public class Table3 {

    @Id
    private long id;
}
```

And I get SQL like:

```
create table "2nd table" (
  id bigint not null,
  col2 bigint not null,
  primary key (col2)
);

create table "3rd table" (
  id bigint not null,
  col3 bigint not null,
  primary key (col3)
);

create table "trade table" (
  id bigint not null,
  col2 varchar(255),
  col3 varchar(255),
  primary key (id)
);

alter table "3rd table"
  add constraint FK7tkn132p8joplte47ce169h82
foreign key (col3)
references "trade table";

alter table "2nd table"
  add constraint FK9jsoykrvn4d0v4aor03g1l324
foreign key (col2)
references "trade table";
```

That looks like something that you would like to do, but I'm not 100% sure...

Comment: based on your answer i reworked my code but its still doing the same thing. i updated my code in question to match what i have now

Comment: i don't want to create classes for table2 and table3. i posted an select statement which should be generated by hibernate automatically. somehow this have to be possible...

Comment: I get this SQL from hibernate log.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why would you do that? If you have the mapped Entity in your `Trade` class you can always access its attributes, but I will try to provide a solution to answer your question.

Well you can do it but you should use a `OneToMany` mapping between both entities (so you should also store the whole mapped Entity too), and use the FK from this Table as an attribute in your Entity and map it like this:

```
@JoinColumn(name="2ndtableID")
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=SecondTable.class,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Message message; 

@Column(name="2ndtableID")
private Long secondTableID;
```

Comment: i don't want to have the whole 2nd/3rd entity in my trade entity as attribute. i just want 1 attribute of these. ill try to make it more understandable in my question

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I am afraid it won't be possible to do it without having those entities as persistent fields.

Comment: i posted the select query which should be executed from hibernate. i think it is somehow possible to tell hibernate to do this

Comment: Surely it will work because of the `join` between the tables. Does your actual Hibernate configuration generate this query?! I doubt it.

Comment: no it doesnt... but this is the one that should be generated

Comment: @XtremeBaumer And what does it return?